# I want to style within JS

Tags: javascript

Issue I have is I can use  tags, but I would like to style particular words. Adding a class doesnt work, is it because I am within script dom ?

Example:

```
var config = [
                {
                    "name"      : "tour_1",
                    "bgcolor"   : "black",
                    "color"     : "white",
                    "position"  : "BR",
                    "text"      : "Customize your user profile, it's easy. This is your shop window on <strong>here</strong> and <strong>there</strong>",
                    "time"      : 4000
                }
```

Instead of strong, I would like to apply class, like

```
<p class="orange">
```

But it wont have it, any suggestions... please

Comment: your code above and description are not overly concise.  can you edit this a little more and add some context and more code?

Comment: Not sure what else you want, I wish to replace <strong> with style class, such as <p class="orange"> or, perhaps inline styling if I must

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget: `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Are you sure you put quotes around it?

Comment: I tried this, "text"      : "Customize your user profile, it's easy. This is your shop window on <p class="orange">here</p> and <strong>there</strong>" and it wouldnt work

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to post a lot more code, and a more exact description of the observed behavior than "it wouldnt work".  If you are passing that config variable to some other program, I wouldn't be too surprised if "text" meant, you know, text and not a mixture of text and tags.

Comment: @422 Don't use double quotes for `"orange"`, use single quotes: `'orange'`. The double quotes around "orange" is ending the string. As a side note, please post what you have tried in your question next time ;)

Comment: @422 - I guess it just wasn't explicit enough. I wasn't sure what you meant by "applying" `<p class="orange">`... does that mean doing string replacement on the existing string, or modifying the DOM after the HTML has been inserted onto the page? Actually typing that code directly into the string was the last thing that would have come to mind. It's a fine question... but I just had no idea what you meant until I read your comment above.

Comment: Cheers Box9.
All sorted now, I add a span class and changed " to ' , looks wicked now, many thanks